# Java static method not caught by try-catch block - why?

Tags: java, exception

Why Java try-catch didn't catch this Exception

Here is code:

class A construct producing a divide zero Exception, which is unexpected in my situation.

and Bar is a class for offering A STATIC method，it will create a static A object. because I only wish A being create once when my program run in his lifetime.

```
public class Test{
    public void foo(){
        try{
            Bar.bar();
        }catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("catch Exception");
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Test obj = new Test();
        obj.foo();
    }
}

class Bar{
    private static A a;
    static {
        a = new A();
    }
    public static void bar() {
    }
}

class A {
    public A(){
        int x = 1/0;
    }
}
```

And on the top of all, I call Bar.bar() method in a big try-catch code block。And I out this Exception infos, I want to know why this try-catch Block didn't catch this Exception and lead to program exit abnormally

```
at.java/jdt_ws/JavaSample_805682b8/bin Test 
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
        at Test.foo(Test.java:4)
        at Test.main(Test.java:12)
Caused by: java.lang.ArithmeticException: / by zero
        at A.<init>(Test.java:28)
        at Bar.<clinit>(Test.java:19)
        ... 2 more
```

any ideas, will be helpful. Is this about static modifier？

Comment: Use _`catch (Throwable t)`_, instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`ExceptionInInitializerError`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/20/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/ExceptionInInitializerError.html) isn't a subclass of [`Exception`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/20/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Exception.html), so it can't be caught by `catch (Exception e)` since it doesn't match the `catch`. You *could* use `catch (Error e)` or even `catch (Throwable t)`, both of which work in at least some implementations ([proof](https://ideone.com/od6uW6)), but in general it's best not to catch `Error` subclasses or `RuntimeException` subclasses.

But note [Irremediable's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76347141/157247) — you can't rely on this being the first access to any of `Bar`'s static features, nor can you rely on the JVM not having had this failure before your `Test.foo` occurs. Nor *should* you rely on those things. :-) Instead, ensure that `Bar` loads correctly.

For details about why you shouldn't rely on the error occuring in code where you can have a `try`/`catch`, see [*Loading of Classes and Interfaces*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se20/html/jls-12.html#jls-12.2) in the Java Language Specification and [Chapter 5](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se20/html/jvms-5.html) of the Java Virtual Machine Specification.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your reply, the real Exception I got is illegalstateexception, is This also not a subclass of Exception, so it can't be caught?

cause I revise here:

class A {
    public A(){
        throw new IllegalStateException();
    }
}

this Exception still not be caught

Comment: Errors can be caught by try/catch as long as the catch expression specifies a type that is a supertype of the error you want to catch.  (One should consider the advisability of so doing).

Comment: @greenhand96 - IllegalStateException is a subclass of Exception.  The Java names are systematic - XyzException is a subclass of Exception, XyzError is a subclass of Error;  Exception and Error are subclasses of Throwable.

Comment: @ArfurNarf right, I look back in my traceback, I found my program first throw NoClassDefFoundError, then IllegalStateException, then lead to A ExceptionInInitializerError, So is conclusion it's because when I call Bar.bar(), It throw A Error not A Exception, So it wouldn't be Caught?

Comment: @greenhand96 - *"the real Exception I got is IllegalStateException"* Not according to your stack trace. Your stack trace shows you getting `ExceptionInInitializerError` (as a result of `Bar`'s initialization failing). It doesn't matter *why* the initialization of `Bar` fails, by the time the error gets to your code, it'll just be `ExceptionInInitializerError` (perhaps with a `cause` you can get via `getCause`).

Answer (score 1):

Along with other answers: there are only one guarantee by JLS - class will be initialized BEFORE first access of its members/methods/constructors or at the moment of invoking Class.forName() method.
So, you can't be sure that Bar class will be initialized exactly in your try-catch clause :)

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I am not sure my understanding is clear enough, you mean Java execute the wrong code block

static {
  A a = new A()
}

not definitely in try-catch block so it wouldn't be caught, 
here is one puzzle for me, cause I debug the code above, and set breakpoint in Bar.bar(), everytime program exit here, is this fit Expectation

Comment: @greenhand96 - What you're seeing when debugging it like that is what it does with this specific code and in that specific version of the specific JVM you're using. But if you had code anywhere else using `Bar`, it's possible the static init would happen elsewhere, or with a different JVM (or even different version of the JVM), the static init could be done outside of any code in your program. All that's guaranteed is that the static init will be done, not that it will be done such that errors in it are propagated to your code. (Not unless you're explicitly doing the load in a class loader).